# How to change apache's default tcp/ip port

Tags: apache

How can I make apache use port 3000 instead of 80 to run my ruby on rails application on an external server?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Edit your `httpd.conf` Find the line that says `Listen 80` and change the 80 to whatever port you want to use.

Don't forget to restart apache.

Answer (score 5):

In
Server version: Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)
Server built:   Feb  1 2014 21:26:04
There is file named ports.conf in /etc/apache2 dir and you can change listening ports from there.

Answer (score 4):

On Ubuntu, it's `/etc/apache2/ports.conf`.