# Apache won't start on xampp: "Apache Service detected with wrong path"

Tags: apache, xampp

3:49:14 PM  [Apache]    Apache Service detected with wrong path

3:49:14 PM  [Apache]    Change XAMPP Apache and Control Panel settings or

3:49:14 PM  [Apache]    Uninstall/disable the other service manually first

3:49:14 PM  [Apache]    Found Path: "C:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice

3:49:14 PM  [Apache]    Expected Path: "c:\program 
files\orangehrm\4.0\apache\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice

Comment: How many Apache instances do you have and how many do you need?

Comment: i dont know how many i have, i only need one to run an application.

Comment: Well, [OrangeHRM](https://www.orangehrm.com/Spanish) should not have put stuff at `c:\program files\orangehrm` without your consent. Is it your own computer or it is someone else's?

Comment: Someone else computer he just asked me to check why orange hrm was not working i am not that familiar with this program

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you have installed another service running like **apache** by itself (without any bundle), or **WAMP** or another bundle that has **apache** server.

You have to check in your programs if you have 2 different apache installed on your pc and then proceed to uninstall 1 of them. I would uninstall both then install again the one I want to keep (**Xampp for example**). It's a good practice after you delete/uninstall a program to use tools like **Ccleaner** to clean the **registry** of your pc that way you ensure the program is "completely" uninstalled of your pc.

If you have to keep more than one **apache instance**. Both of then are pointing to the same direction and port by default. You have to change the port that way you can enter to localhost (**localhost:8080 by default**) and **localhost:8083** (another port used to run other apache instance) and so on as many instances of apache you have.

You can read more here:

1) [Apache default ip port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693147/how-to-change-apaches-default-tcp-ip-port)

2) [apache tcp/ip port](https://helpdeskgeek.com/networking/change-apache-listening-port/)

3) [2 apache instances on your pc](https://serverfault.com/questions/121048/can-i-run-2-different-apache-servers-on-the-same-machine-on-different-ports)